# Passing parameter as clob associative array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, oracle, clob, associative

i have an issue when inserting string as clob from C#.
Let me explain first what i'm doing:

i have declared in a package the following type

```
TYPE assocarrayclob_t IS TABLE OF CLOB INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

than i use it in my stored procude to insert into a table which is the following

```
create or replace PACKAGE JOT_PAY_100603_PKG AS
PROCEDURE INS(
I_NUMBER_OF_VALUES  number
,I_TASK_NODEREF number
,I_HASHES   nav_mgr.assocarrayvarchar2_t
,I_TAG_UNIQUE   nav_mgr.assocarrayvarchar2_t
,I_HAS_LOG_RECORDS  nav_mgr.assocarraynumber_t
,I_COMPRESSED_VALUES    nav_mgr.assocarrayclob_t
,I_ROW_ID   nav_mgr.assocarraynumber_t
,O_RES_SET  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR

) ;
```

the table where tha data goes has a column of clob.
i'm using bulk insert so on c# i'm creating an array of string for the parameter I_COMPRESSED_VALUES.

The problem is that it does not work and oracle is complaining with the following error

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [15419], [severe error during     PL/SQL execution], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

ORA-06544: PL/SQL: internal error, arguments: [78502], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06553: PLS-801: internal error [78502]
```

any idea how to fix this?